# which libp2p module do I use to broadcast data to peers in the network e.g blockchain? do I use mdns or kademlia for blockchain?

Tags: substrate, go-ethereum, dht, kademlia, libp2p

I am trying to understand lib2p2 Rust by looking at the [rust libp2p examples](https://github1s.com/libp2p/rust-libp2p/blob/master/examples/chat/Cargo.toml#L15) in the rust libp2p github repo and [substrate network module](https://github1s.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/HEAD/substrate/client/network/src/transport.rs#L35-L36) as well.
My question is, If I am building a peer to peer network such as a blockchain using libp2p.

1. If I am correct , do I use both kadamlia and mdns for peer discovery ? or I can use only mdns or only kadamlia since both can be used for peer discovery according to the libp2p documentation
2. If I used kademlia for discovery and routing, does this mean my network will also connect with the ipfs network? I came across information mentioning that ipfs is coupled with the kademlia protocol. how do I use rust libp2p such that the peers in my protocol network (e.g blockhain) only connect with other peers running my own protocol such as a blockchain network? is there a code sample for this ?
3. What libp2p behavior or module to I use for broadcasting information to other peers in the network ? such as broadcasting blocks as in a blockchain network ? is it gossipsub? I looked into the substrate network crate Cargo.toml but i saw that the gossipsub feature is not enabled